# C#: Get file large thumbnails/previews, instead of large icons, using SHGetImageList and SHGetFileInfo, like Windows Explorer

Tags: c#, winforms, shell, listview, native

I'm using C#, Windows Forms, Net 2.0.

I'm using SHGetImageList to get the system image list with, let's say, SHIL_JUMBO parameter and get large 256x256 images on Windows 7.

```
[DllImport(SHELL32, EntryPoint = "#727")]
public static extern int SHGetImageList(int imageList, ref Guid riid, ref IntPtr handle);

public static IntPtr Get(SystemImageListType type)
{
    IntPtr handle = IntPtr.Zero;
    NativeMethods.SHGetImageList((int)type, ref NativeMethods.IIDImageList, ref handle);
    return handle;
}
```

I'm also using

```
NativeMethods.SendMessage(listView.Handle, LVM_SETIMAGELIST, LVSIL_NORMAL, imageListHandle);
```

to set the system image list to my listview, and

```
public static int GetFileIconIndex(string pathName)
{
    NativeMethods.SHFILEINFO shfiData = new NativeMethods.SHFILEINFO();

    NativeMethods.SHGetFileInfo(
        pathName,
        0,
        ref shfiData,
        Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(NativeMethods.SHFILEINFO)),
        NativeMethods.SHGFI.SYSICONINDEX |
        NativeMethods.SHGFI.LARGEICON |
        NativeMethods.SHGFI.ICON );
    return shfiData.iIcon;
}
```

to get the icon index of different files/folders loaded in the listview.

Everything works fine, except I get large 256 icons even for movie or image files, where I would expect a thumbnail (preview of the image/movie), like in Windows Explorer.

How can I get the thumbnails, not the icons for files that are displayed as thumbnails in Windows Explorer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows Vista and above you can use [IThumbnailProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms631826.aspx) interface.

There is a wraper for that in [Windows API Code Pack](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack).

For XP there is different interface, see this: http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/NET/Code/Libraries/Shell_Projects/Thumbnail_Extraction/Thumbail_Tester_Code_zip_ThumbnailTester/ThumbnailCreator_cs.asp

Obviously, you must decide which files will use system image list icons and which will use thumbnails.